# How can I easily retab html files according to some sane default?

Tags: vim, automation, file-format

I have some html files that I'd like to retab that look like this:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
                    <img src="images/logo.png">
                    <div class="userbox">
                            <div class="welcome">Welcome Andy!</div>
                            <div class="blackbox">
                                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Invite Friends</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
</header>
```

And I want them to look something like this:

```
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
    <div class="userbox">
      <div class="welcome">Welcome Andy!</div>
        <div class="blackbox">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Invite Friends</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Or some sane default. What's the easiest way to go about doing this from the terminal in ubuntu for all of the html files in the current directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `vim`:

```
:set softtabstop=0
:set expandtab
:set smarttab
:set shiftwidth=2
gg=G
:retab
```

EDIT: Explainations:

- lines 1-3: sane default
- line 4: indent with 2 spaces
- line 5:

  - `gg`: top line
  - `=`: indent until...
  - `G`: ...end
- line 6: insure that all tabs are converted to spaces

Comment: You probably should mention that those are vi commands.

Comment: Indeed, I should, (the question appeared in my 'vim' category)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install tidy
cd whatever_dir_you_want
find . -name '*.html' -exec tidy -m {} \;
```

Note: this probably wont play nice with inline-php. Play around with `tidy` (without the `-m` argument) to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I used Stéphane Chazelas' solution for [reindenting a file with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47210/) along with dogbane's solution on [how to repeat a string 'n' times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/) to compose this invocation that will change the indentation of a file that uses spaces for indentation:

```bsh
# Repeat a string "n" times e.g. repeatstr abc 3
#
# Solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/
repeatstr() {
  printf "%.0s$1" $(seq 1 $2)
}

# Reindent file that uses spaces
#   e.g. reindent 2 4 index.html
#   e.g. cat index.html | reindent 2 4
#
# Solution from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47210/
reindent() {
  if [[ $# -gt 2 ]]; then
    f=$(mktemp)
    cat $3 | reindent $1 $2 > $f && mv $f $3
  else
    sed "h;s/[^ ].*//;s/$(repeatstr ' ' $1)/$(repeatstr ' ' $2)/g;G;s/\n *//"
  fi
}
```

Add these functions to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, and then just run:

```
reindent 4 2 index.html
```

If the indentation is imperfect to begin with, I would first run the file through a "pretty print" formatting utility such as [tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) for HTML or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Are those tabs in the first example and spaces in the next? Here's a shell script that could change tabs to two spaces. Change working directory to location of HTML files.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.html
do
    sed 's/\t/  /g' "${i}" > filename.notabs && mv filename.notabs "${i}"
done
```

UPDATE

I just had need to do something similar. I went strait for [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit/downloads)'s replace-in-files feature. It's very nice if you have GUI access to the files.

[image]